# How define a three dimensional float matrix in Emgu

Tags: c#, opencv, matrix, multidimensional-array, emgucv

I need to define a three dimensional matrix in EmguCV for storing the features of my training dataset which are floats. So I should have a matrix which the number of its rows is the size of the training set, the number of its columns is static 30 and its depth is the length of my feature vector(20). the pseudocode is:

```
Matrix<float[]> TrainFeatures = new Matrix<float>(Trainset.Num, 30, 20);
```

As Matrix definition in Emgu is a bi-dimensional and I can't find any documentation for MatND in Emgu or OpenCV, How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and thought maybe it's useful for others:
I used [The Answer in this LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611008/how-to-declare-matrix-array-in-emgu-cv) and it was useful So I defined a three dimensional matrix like this:

```
Matrix<float> TrainFeatures = new Matrix<float>[Trainset.Num];
for (int count = 0; count < TrainingFeatures.Length; count++)
         {
             TrainFeatures[count] = new Matrix<float>(30, 20);
         }
```