# Get values 1 or 0 of binary images

Tags: visual-studio-2010, emgucv

I have my code That consist: I open the images that I want to upload, then I convert it in grayscale and later in binary image. But I have a question. How do I get values (0,1) of binary image in order to create a matrix with that values with emgucv c#??

```
      OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          Image<Gray, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Gray, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
          pictureBox1.Image = My_Image.ToBitmap();

          My_Image = My_Image.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(69), new Gray(255));
          pictureBox2.Image = My_Image.ToBitmap();


      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Second Post

I think I misunderstood the question, sorry for giving wrong info. But I think you may get some understanding from this post? [Work with matrix in emgu cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197153/work-with-matrix-in-emgu-cv)

---

### First post

By passing your My_Image which is result after ThresholdBinary() to following function, you can have **array of zero and one only** about the binary image.

```
public int[] ZeroOneArray(Image<Gray, byte> binaryImage)
{
    //get the bytes value after Image.ThresholdBinary() 
    //either 0 or 255
    byte[] imageBytes = binaryImage.Bytes;
    //change 255 to 1 and remain 0
    var binary_0_Or_255 = from byteInt in imageBytes select byteInt / 255;
    //convert to array
    int[] arrayOnlyOneOrZero = binary_0_Or_255.ToArray();
    //checking the array content
    foreach (var bin in arrayOnlyOneOrZero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bin);
    }
    return arrayOnlyOneOrZero;
}
```

Is this what you want? thanks

---

### Third Post

By understanding this, [chris answer in error copying image to array](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4317), I write a function for you to transfer your **gray binary image** to **gray** matrix image

```
public Image<Gray, double> GrayBinaryImageToMatrixImage(Image<Gray, byte> binaryImage)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = binaryImage.Bytes;
    Image<Gray, double> gray_image_div = new Image<Gray, double>(binaryImage.Size);//empty image method one
    //or
    Image<Gray, double> gray_image_div_II = binaryImage.Convert<Gray, double>().CopyBlank();//empty image method two

    //transfer binaryImage array to gray image matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryImage.Width; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < binaryImage.Height; j++)
            {
                if (imageBytes[i*binaryImage.Width+j] == 0)
                {
                    //grey image only one channel
                    gray_image_div.Data[i, j, 0] = 0;
                }
                else if (imageBytes[i*binaryImage.Width+j] == 255)
                {
                    gray_image_div.Data[i, j, 0] = 255;
                }

            }
        }
        return gray_image_div;
}
```

Comment: I will read your answer.The rhink is that I want use pixel like input to neural network. for that reason I read about give NN 1 or 0 as input and I want to get that values fron binary image!

Comment: then may be u can get the 1 or 0 value from my first post part I think. It change the binaryImage bytes to either 1 or 0